# Unable to get to switch_root mode in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos-7, grub2, chroot, dracut

I am trying to reset the root password on my old drive, and I followed this instruction:
https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/recover-root-passwd

However, instead of booting into a 'rescue' prompt as the article suggested, I got a dracut prompt that I can't run `chroot /sysroot`.

Any suggestion?